# excel index function implementation needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in the following formula,

i need to search for each row in sheet one, all rows in **sheet2**, in columns **B** and **D**, and get from there the corresponding values:

```
=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2),Sheet2!Z2 & "|" & Sheet2!Y2,"")

=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D:D),Sheet2!Z#INDEX_of_lineWHICHMATCHESCRITERIA & "|" & Sheet2!Y#INDEX_of_lineWHICHMATCHESCRITERIA,"")
```

I have not figured how to properly use the `INDEX` function to achieve this, combined with the above formula

i put the task in detail:
I have an excel file. The task needed to be accomplished, is the following: for each row (actually for each id, stored in column A - which exists in sheet 1 ) that the following condition is true:

column E (which exists in sheet 1) = column B (which exists in sheet 2) AND column C (which exists in sheet 1) = column D (which exists in sheet 2),

i must insert data from column Z (which exists in sheet 2) and column Y (which exists in sheet 2) to column X (which exists in sheet 1).

If column X, has already data in it, all new inserted data must have | as a separator, and should be inserted in front of the existing value.

If no data exist in column Z, or Y, then nothing is inserted to column X.

I have tried without success, to use index match, but no luck, i think something more complicated is needed. How can i do this with an excel formula? How the below formula should be transformed, in order to get the row that fulfils the conditions? =X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2),Sheet2!Z2 & "|" & Sheet2!Y2,"")

=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D:D),Sheet2!Z#lineWHICHMATCHESCRITERIA & "|" & Sheet2!Y#lineWHICHMATCHESCRITERIA,"")

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B, MATCH(criteria, Sheet2!$B:$B, 0))` where criteria is the value you are trying to match.

Comment: what confuses me, is that i must match row 2 from sheet 1, with another row from sheet2, and the criteria is E2=value in columnB AND value from C2 -value from the corresponding row from column D, how should i make the above formula in order to get the values i want?

Comment: You can match two values as per the above by defining two look up values, for example `{=MATCH(Sheet1!$E2&Sheet1!$C2,Sheet2!$B:$B&Sheet2!$D:$D, 0)}` just remember to enter with `CTRL+SHFT+ENTER`

Comment: =X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2),Sheet2!Z2 & "|" & Sheet2!Y2,"")
 for the condition met AND Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2, i need to extract value from column Z and Y, still confused how i should combine your suggestion with my formula...

Comment: Me too, put some sample data up. In your comment above it says `IF A = B` AND `IF A = B`, why check the same thing twice? You need to read through Boris' answer below, and then search for INDEX MATCH Multiple Values.

Comment: i have updated the question in detail, hope this helps

Comment: Not at all, are you checking that Col E = Col B, or do you wants Col E value to be Col B value? If so what value are you looking up?

Comment: col E must equal col B, and col C, must equal col D. E and C combined make a unique key, to identify the row. Same holds true, for sheet 2, and col B and D. Thus the AND in the formula, and the IF is used, in order to get the value from the corresponding excel cells, only if a value exists there For each row in sheet 1, i must take the combination of col E, and C, and search for a match, in sheet 2, col B and D. Then for that row in sheet2, i must extract the columns' values, from columns Z, and Y, and merge them with the value column X has from sheet 1

Comment: Right now I understand, and you have already got the correct formula, `=X2&"|" & IF(AND(Sheet1!E2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C2=Sheet2!D2),Sheet2!Z2 & "|" & Sheet2!Y2,"")`. Wheres the issue?

Comment: the above formula, searches only on row 2, and returns from row 2 of sheet 2, if criteria holds true. Issue: the task i need to accomplish, for each row of sheet 1, search in all rows of sheet 2, and return the corresponding value, so an index match function must be entered in the above, but have not managed to combine the index match, with the above formula... The above formula must be combined with an array index match formula...

Comment: Just drag that formula down and it will work for row 2, 3, 4, however far you drag it, or is this formula in a single cell? In which case what conditions are you matching? Or do you want to return all matches of all rows in a single cell?

Comment: in a new cell, of sheet 1, i need for that row, say row 2 and cell E2, search in the whole col B of sheet2, and for the value found in C2, search in the whole D column, of sheet2, for a row that matches, then return from this particular row found in sheet 2, the values of column Z, Y, if they exist. So dragging the above is not the solution i need, an index match formula must be added in the context. One row of sheet1, matches exactly one row of sheet2

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you grasp the logic behind `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

`INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])` - returns value from cell.

- **array** - range of cells that you want the result from.
- **row_num** - number of the row that you want result from.
- **column_num** - number of the column that you want result from.

Note: Row / column number is relative to selected range.

Examples:

- `INDEX(A1:A5,3)` will return value from A3
- `INDEX(A5:A10,3)` will return value from A8
- `INDEX(A1:G1,3)` will return value from C1

`MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])` - returns row / column of first match.

Note: returned row / column number is relative to selected range.

- **lookup_value** - this is the number or text you are looking for and it can be a value or a cell reference.
- **lookup_array** - range of cells in which you want to search for the value.
- **match_type** - this is a parameter that tells formula should it return exact match or nearest value.

Example:

- `MATCH("Cat",A1:A5,0)` will return row number of cell that has value "Cat"

Now, if you combine those two it will look like this:

`INDEX (column to return a value from, (MATCH (lookup value, column to search from, 0))`

- **column to return a value from** - range of cells that you want the result from.
- **lookup value** - value for which you would like to find corresponding data.
- **column to search from** - range of cells in which you want to search for the value.

Example:

- `INDEX(B1:B5,MATCH("Cat",A1:A5,0)` will find `Cat` in column `A` and return value from the same row of column `B`.